# array(['<=50K', '>50K'], dtype=object) not running

Tags: python

I am following this code here: https://www.guru99.com/scikit-learn-tutorial.html

When I run:

```
array(['<=50K', '>50K'], dtype=object)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: array.array() takes no keyword arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up [Python's `array`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) with [numpy's ones](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array).

If you are importing `numpy` as `np` as it is usually done, then you should you should qualify the call:

```
np.array(...)
```